# Multilple Downloads not working while using URLSessionDownloadTask in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am trying to download multilple files using the session download task and following happens:

1. First download starts. I guess it creates a temporary file for example CFNetworkDownload_Kx54Ke.tmp.
2. Soon after my second download start which by the way uses the same session object but a different downloadtask object.
3. I see that my first download stop and errors out with following error :

   __NSCFLocalDownloadFile: error 2 opening for ioChannel, file: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E88FD72B-AB73-402E-B264-D5827BA2023C/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_Kx54Ke.tmp
4. My second download however finishes with no issues.

My session code. I am just passing a URL to this method and session is created only once in the life cycle of the app:

```
//creating session only once in the app life cycle

init() {

    super.init()
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    self.session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }

//calling download method from my viewcontroller
func download(url : URL ){
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            let downloadTask : URLSessionDownloadTask

                 downloadTask  = self.session!.downloadTask(with: request)


            downloadTask.resume()
}
```

UPDATE:
Calling each different download operation inside operation queue block works and I can see the downloads being in parallel. However I would still like to confirm if this behavior is expected with Swift 3 in urlsessiondownload task.

Comment: Multiple simultaneous download tasks are perfectly viable, as I have demonstrated elsewhere. It would be better if (1) you had an explicit delegate queue and (2) you showed your delegate methods in your question, since who knows what the heck you're doing there...

Comment: @matt I am not sure what you meant by point number 1. I have added my code for viewcontroller  at http://pastebin.com/Pd7CMtGB and my networking class here : http://pastebin.com/PMmxFrt1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was a stupid mistake on my end. I was clearing out the temp directory on every download call. First download clears temp directory and create a temp file.  Second download call clears out the temp directory including the temp file of the first download.

I had to move the clear temp directory call to a location where it's called only once.

Comment: "I was clearing out the temp directory on every download call." Just as I suspected. But this why I said we need to see your delegate code. A question asked without showing the relevant code is useless (and not in a pastebin — right here, as part of the question). As for (1), you are passing `nil` as your queue, which might not give the results you want.